# How to show static image in react native

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native

In an app I am currently working on I have a main menu screen(DashboardMain) presented when the app is loaded.
DashboardMain consist of several DashIcon components which are custom buttons that receive a 'source' prop in order to render an image.
when I pass the component a source prop in the DashboardMain component I get a parsing error for the file location and an expected global() call for the require method. Can anyone please explain how to fix this.

The file directory looks like this:

```
dashboard_components(folder)
           |
   ________|_______________
   |                      |
DashboardMain.js    dashImages(folder)
                          |
                 _________|____________
                 |                    |
        profileInformation.jpg     index.js
```

Here is the code:

```
class DashboardMain extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HomeCard>
        <IconFieldRow>
          <DashIcon
            iconName='Profile Information'    
            source{require('./dashImages/profileInformation.png')}     
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('Info');
            }}
          />
```

Comment: Got it working thanks with the solutions below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is the code specifies a png when the file is a jpg.

You can also import the image this way:

```
import profileInformationImg from './dashImages/profileInformation.jpg'
```

And specify it as the source:

```
<DashIcon source={profileInformationImg}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Andy, after correcting my typo and trying out your suggestion it still comes back with a parsing error. Any other info you could offer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just do

```
import ImageName from './dashImages/profileInformation.jpg';
 class DashboardMain extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HomeCard>
        <IconFieldRow>
          <DashIcon
            iconName='Profile Information' source= {ImageName} onPress={() => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('Info');
            }}
          />
```

Comment: Tried this and am still getting a parsing error, an other tips.

Answer (score 0):

```
import profileInformation from './dashImages/profileInformation.png';

class DashboardMain extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <HomeCard>
            <IconFieldRow>
              <DashIcon
                iconName='Profile Information'    
                source={profileInformation}     
                onPress={() => {
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('Info');
                }}
              />
```

Comment: Tried this and am still getting a parsing error, any other tips?